# INSERT MySQL statement: current values and selected value INTO VALUES from same table

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sql-insert

I want to insert current values, which is `BlockData`, `BlockHash`, and `dataid` from client side, and only `BlockLastHash` I want to select its value from the last row in the same table. However, `BlockLastHash` saves the command itself not the value.

The code:

```
    connection.query("INSERT INTO `pow` (`BlockData`, `BlockHash`, `BlockLastHash`, `dataid`) VALUES ('"+blockdata+"', '"+hash+"', '( SELECT `BlockHash` FROM `pow` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 )' , '"+id+"') ", (err, res) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("1 Block inserted");  
    });
```

The output in `BlockLastHash` is the same command which is

```
( SELECT `BlockHash` FROM `pow` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 )
```

How to solve this please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: **WARNING**: Use *placeholder values* to store data, do **NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation. This is usually really easy even with the low-level [MySQL driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries).

Comment: ` var sql = "INSERT INTO `pow` (`BlockData`, `BlockHash`, `BlockLastHash`, `dataid`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";` `var inserts = [blockdata, hash, 'SELECT `BlockHash` FROM `pow` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1',id];` `sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);` How to put the select statement in the values in  this form, please?

Comment: It's literally right there in the documentation I linked. For a subselect, just put that in the main query and placeholder *only* the data values. `SELECT ..., 'SELECT ...'` will select the *text*. You'd be better off with a `JOIN`.

Comment: Do not enclose the select into single quotes - that transforms the select into a string literal. However, in this particular case, it may be better if you executed the select first with a locking read and then perform the insert using that value, as the insert and the select both use the same table.